# Removing SwiftSpinner cocoapods import module from project in swift

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I've installed a cocoapods in my project but now I want to remove it from project. I did all I can find from internet.
I have removed the framework and embedded binaries.
But still when I write "import SwiftSpinner" at top of any .swift files the project auto-completes it and project runs without error.
How can I remove this in a way that it wouldn't be listed in my modules as well?
By the way this only happens in my current project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to remove the swifspinner from your project? If yes,

Remove the Pod **pod 'SwiftSpinner'** from your podfile and run pod install again.

This will solve your problem.

Comment: Yes; But whatever I do I still see it in the import module list.

Comment: this solution solved your problem. this is because when we install a pod a Podfile.lock is created. and removing pod and installing it again amend that file accordingly.